# Validacion de un Login en Flask

Tags: python, validación, flask

Tengo una validacion de un login en flask pero no entiendo muy bien la estructura

primero uso la funcion que validara los datos que se llenen en el form cuando se apriete el boton de iniciar sesion,

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

luego validamos que el usuario exista en la bdd, con este codigo

```
attempted_user = User.query.get( form.username.data).first()
```

me estoy guiando de un tutorial en youtube en esta parte que luego de verificar que el usuario exista entonces verifica si las claves son iguales, sin embargo se utilizo el modulo bycript para encriptar las claves cuando se almacenaran en la bdd entonces tendriamos que utilizar otra forma para verificar que las dos claves, la que la persona ponga y la que esta almacenada sean iguales
el codigo es este, sin embargo no lo entiendo:

```
if attempted_user and attempted_user.check_password_correction(attempted_password = form.password.data): 
login_user(attempted_user) 
flash('iniciaste sesion')
```

el codigo anterior es soportado por esta funcion en el archivo models.py:

```
def check_password_correction(self, attempted_password):
return bcrypt.check_password_hash, attempted_password)
```

sin embargo no entiendo mucho a que se refiere, creo que decodificar la clave y luego verificarla con la clave hash?

si alguien pudiera explicarme los dos ultimos codigos a que se refieren seria bueno por favor

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras parece incompleto. La última línea que pones:

```
   return bcrypt.check_password_hash, attempted_password)
```

es claramente un error de sintaxis, pues cierra un paréntesis al final que no se abrió antes. Lo más probable es que esa línea sea algo de este estilo:

```py
   return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password_hash, attempted_password)
```

Este es un patrón muy típico que se encuentra en varios repositorios de código en github, en los que probablemente se ha basado el curso que estás viendo. Asumiendo que esa sea en efecto la sintaxis, la explicación de lo que hace sería la siguiente.

### Contraseñas "hasheadas"

Es típico que las contraseñas de usuario no se guarden "sin más" (es decir, en texto plano) en la base de datos, pues si esta base de datos se viera comprometida (alguien pudiera leer la información que hay en ella) tendría inmediatamente acceso a todas las contraseñas.

Para evitar esto, las contraseñas podrían cifrarse, pero entonces aparecería otro problema. Para poder comparar la contraseña que el usuario envía en el login con la que tenemos en la base de datos sería necesario descifrar ésta, por lo que sería necesario suministrar al código la clave con la que fue cifrado. Esa clave ¿dónde estaría? Si estuviera formando parte del propio código, cualquiera con acceso al mismo podría leerla, y por tanto usarla para descifrar todas las contraseñas de la base de datos. Si la tenemos guardada fuera del código ¿dónde la guardamos? Cualquier sitio que usemos para guardar esa "clave maestra" sería otro riesgo de seguridad similar a haber guardado directamente las contraseñas en la base de datos. Un atacante que tuviera acceso a nuestro sistema podría acceder también al lugar donde esté guardada la "clave maestra" y usarla entonces para descifrar las contraseñas de la base de datos.

Por esta razón tampoco se guardan cifradas, sino *hasheadas*. Mucha gente no entiende la diferencia y supone que el *hash* es algún tipo de cifrado, pero en realidad es algo más sutil.

Una función *hash* es irreversible. Si a la función hash le pasas una cadena cualquiera (la contraseña del usuario), lo que te devuelve es otra cadena, a partir de la cual es **imposible** recuperar la cadena originalmente hasheada. Por tanto no está cifrada (ya que algo cifrado podría descifrarse). Es una vía de dirección única: contraseña -> hash. No existe la vía inversa hash->contraseña.

Entonces, guardando el resultado del hash estamos a salvo. Aunque alguien consiguiera acceso a la base de datos y pudiera leer todos los nombres de usuario, no podría obtener las contraseñas, sólo los hashes de las contraseñas. Nadie puede obtener la contraseña a partir del hash (ni siquiera teniendo la función hash que se ha usado, pues como se ha dicho es de una sola dirección).

Pero en ese caso ¿cómo verificar si un usuario ha proporcionado la contraseña correcta en el login, si es imposible saber cual era la contraseña original? La respuesta en realidad es sencilla. Aplicamos la función hash también a la contraseña que el usuario haya proporcionado en el login. Si proporcionó la contraseña correcta, el resultado deberá coincidir con el que teníamos en la base de datos, ya que la misma cadena de entrada produce siempre el mismo hash.

### Ataques de fuerza bruta y "rainbow tables"

La única forma en la que un atacante (que haya conseguido acceso a la base de datos) podría encontrar la contraseña de un usuario, es mediante lo que se llama "fuerza bruta" que no es más que ir probando una a una todas las contraseñas posibles, y calculando en hash de cada una para comparar el resultado con lo que había en la base de datos. Así, por ejemplo, prueba como contraseña "012345" y saca un hash. Lo compara con el que hay en la base de datos, ve que no coinciden. Esa no era la contraseña. Prueba ahora "holamundo", saca el hash, lo compara y ¡bingo! ha encontrado la contraseña (por eso hay que elegir cadenas muy largas y poco comunes, para que la cantidad de pruebas que haya que hacer sea astronómica y el tiempo necesario para dar con ella haga que no merezca la pena).

Pero fíjate en un detalle. Imagina que por fuerza bruta descubre que un usuario usaba como contraseña "holamundo". El hash de esa cadena se encontró en la base de datos. Ahora imagina que varios usuarios estaban usando esa misma clave. Todos tendrían en la base de datos el mismo hash almacenado, por lo que el atacante acaba de descubrir la clave de todos ellos de un solo golpe de suerte.

Es más. El atacante podría antes incluso de haber conseguido acceso a la base de datos, haber preparado una enorme tabla de contraseñas comunes y de cuáles son sus hashes. Entonces cuando consiga acceso a la base de datos sólo tiene que comparar los hashes que él tenía precalculados con los que haya en la base de datos, para descubrir si alguien estaba usando como contraseña una de las que él ya tenía pre-hasheadas. Esa tabla puede ser muy grande, generarla puede llevarle tiempo, pero después podría usarla para encontrar muchas claves en muy poco tiempo. Esto es un *ataque rainbow table*.

### Sal y pimienta

Para evitar los ataques *rainbow table* típicamente se añade a la contraseña de cada usuario una cadena llamada "sal". Se pone delante de la contraseña y se calcula el hash del resultado. Esa "sal" es aleatoria y diferente en cada usuario. De ese modo, aún si dos usuarios usan la misma contraseña sus hashes serían diferentes, porque su "sal" es diferente. Además es imposible que el atacante pueda pre-fabricar la tabla rainbow pues no sabe de antemano la sal usada en cada uno.

Para poder verificar ahora la contraseña que el usuario proporciona en el login el programa debe añadir a esa contraseña proporcionada la cadena "sal" y hashear el resultado, para compararlo con lo que haya en la base de datos. Pero ¿cómo sabe el programa qué sal se usó? La solución es que esa sal se guarde también en la propia contraseña hasheada, al inicio de la misma.

Un atacante que consiga acceso a la base de datos tendría acceso por tanto a todas las "sales", pero aún así debería volver a usar fuerza bruta con cada contraseña, y el hecho de romper una de ellas no le permite deducir ninguna otra.

Finalmente a veces también se añade "pimienta" a las contraseñas antes de hashearlas. La pimienta, al igual que la sal, sería otra cadena aleatoria que se pone delante, pero en este caso no estaría almacenada en la base de datos sino en otro lugar. Esto sólo pone las cosas un poco más difíciles al atacante que deberá conseguir acceso a la base de datos, y además a ese otro lugar donde está la pimienta (y aún teniendo ambos, todavía tendría que intentar por fuerza bruta todas las contraseñas posibles para romper una sola).

### Tu código

Así pues vemos que para generar la información adecuada para guardar en la base de datos se necesita:

- Generar una "sal" aleatoria
- Generar opcionalmente "pimienta" (esta no la usaría tu ejemplo)
- Elegir un algoritmo de hasheado criptográfico entre los diferentes que existen
- Concatenar a la contraseña del usuario la sal
- Usar la función hash sobre la cadena resultante
- Añadir como prefijo al hash resultante cuál ha sido la sal utilizada (y en ocasiones también el nombre del algoritmo de hash criptográfico utilizado)
- Guardar la cadena resultante en la base de datos

De todo lo anterior (salvo el guardado en la base de datos) se ocupa `bcrypt.generate_password_hash(contraseña)`, que es una función que no aparece en tu código, pero que seguro que has tenido que usar. Es el resultado de esa función lo que se almacena en el objeto `User`, en su campo `self.password_hash` (y por tanto también en la columna del mismo nombre en la base de datos).

Esa contraseña hasheada tendrá típicamente una pinta como la siguiente:

```
$2b$12$aAi7GkkUyMyFqFe9nGQww.FbcE9CiZ4HaofJvkViYxRvW6XFTS8zW
```

En ella vemos una parte inicial, que en concreto es `$2b$12$aAi7GkkUyMyFqFe9nGQww.Fb`, que corresponde a la "sal" que ha sido generada aleatoriamente (aunque la primera parte de esta sal `$2b$12$` es fija si no se cambian los valores por defecto del generador de sal)

El resto de esa cadena, en concreto `cE9CiZ4HaofJvkViYxRvW6XFTS8zW`, es el resultado de hashear la sal más la contraseña del usuario.

Ahora, para verificar que el usuario sabe la contraseña, se la preguntamos. Si su respuesta está en la variable `attempted_password` lo que deberíamos hacer sería:

- Extraer de `password_hash` la parte correspondiente a la sal. En este caso sería como dijimos `$2b$12$aAi7GkkUyMyFqFe9nGQww.Fb`
- Concatenar esa sal con lo que el usuario respondió, el contenido de `attempted_password`
- Hashear el resultado
- Comparar el resultado con el resto de `password_hash`, es decir, con `cE9CiZ4HaofJvkViYxRvW6XFTS8zW`.
- Si coinciden, el usuario ha proporcionado la contraseña correcta. Si no coinciden, ha proporcionado una contraseña incorrecta.

Precisamente estas operaciones son las que realiza la función `bcrypt.check_password()`, si le pasas como primer parámetro el valor de `password_hash` (incluyendo la sal y todo lo demás) y como segundo parámetro la contraseña proporcionada por el usuario.

Por ejemplo, si le metemos una clave incorrecta:

```
>>> bcrypt.check_password_hash("$2b$12$aAi7GkkUyMyFqFe9nGQww.FbcE9CiZ4HaofJvkViYxRvW6XFTS8zW", "una clave")
False
```

En cambio:

```
>>> bcrypt.check_password_hash("$2b$12$aAi7GkkUyMyFqFe9nGQww.FbcE9CiZ4HaofJvkViYxRvW6XFTS8zW", "holamundo")
True
```

¡Ops! He revelado mi contraseña :-)